# Issue rendering react app from express server

Tags: reactjs, express

I get the following error when i try to render react app using express server:

Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.

app.js from express :

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');

var emp = require('./routes/employeeRoute');

var app = express();



// view engine setup
//app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
//app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));

app.use(cors());

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/api/', employees);
app.use('/api/employees', employees);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Why doesn't it render the react app ? I have no idea about where I am going wrong. Can anyone give me a basic idea about how to do this?

I have the following in route:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    Employee.find({}, function (err, emp) {
    if(err){
       res.send(err)
    }else{
      res.json(emp);
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: Show files in `views` diectory

Comment: check if the '/' route is displaying the correct json, if it is then your front-end rendering logic is failing somewhere.